# Where can I find sample code for adding effects to photos on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-4.2

Is there any sample source codes or reference information about adding effects to photos that is available for the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Apple’s [GLImageProcessing sample](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/)  should get you started.

Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/) also